# xcode crash report

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash-reports

i do receive an app crash report while testing app. i dont really understand the app crash report.
the uses pjsip connects to voip server and does some xml parsing using lua script.
the app crashes during testing. can someone please take a look at the crash rerport and tell what does the report really say. is it using too much memory? reason timeout on socket? waht does it mean?
overheating the cpu?

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Kernel version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Wed Oct 10 23:29:02 PDT 2012; root:xnu-   2107.2.34~2/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2013-01-16 22:03:05 +0100
Exception Code:      0xdeadfeed
Reason:              Timeout on socket /var/run/lockdown/checkin.2732 waiting for     com.apple.crashreportmover to checkin for Xcode. spawn=1358370169 select=1358370169 now=1358370184
Thermal Level:       0
Thermal Sensors:    3264 3017 5310 3268 3323 3193 3161 3516 3500 3496 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Frontmost process PID:    2952
Frontmost process PID:    66
Jetsam Level:              0
Free Pages:            36939
Active Pages:          24076
Inactive Pages:         9098
Purgeable Pages:        5613
Wired Pages:           17742
Speculative Pages:      5277
Throttled Pages:       36039
Busy Buffer Count:         0
Pages Wanted:              0
Pages Reclaimed:           0
```

i cant find information about the exception code

```
Exception Code:      0xdeadfeed
```

Comment: overheating cpu would result in 0xc00010ff (cool off) I haven't ever seen or heard of 0xdeadfeed (dead feed). this may help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html